# Neo4j: Match multiple destination nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to efficiently construct a query of the form:

MATCH (a)-[:Foo]->(b) WHERE (a)-[:Bar]->(c) AND (a)-[:Bar]->(d) RETURN a

which is a query for

```
       [Foo]----(b)
(a)---|
       [Bar]----(c)
      |
       [Bar]----(d)
```

However I would like to have a variable number of destination nodes with relationship Bar (not just c and d, but any list of nodes).

Another way to say it: Return 'a' if it has Bar relationship to [c,d,...] list of nodes

Currently I manually concatenate the WHERE clause as on top, but I feel like there is a sexier way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a sexier way for this. See http://console.neo4j.org/r/8zx2l2 for a minimal setup of this in Neo4j console. I've used the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:Foo]->(b)
WITH a
MATCH (a)-[:Bar]->(other)
WITH a, count(other) AS count
WHERE count=2
RETURN a
```

The `WHERE` condition checks if the number of paths equals your requirement (assuming 2 here). So you need only one where check. Is that sexy enough ;-) ?

#### addendum

In case you want to make sure that the `other` nodes are in a given list of target nodes:

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:Foo]->(b)
WITH a
MATCH (a)-[:Bar]->(other)
WITH a, count(other) AS count, collect(other) as others
WHERE all(x in [c,d,....] WHERE x in others) 
RETURN a
```

This makes sure that `a` has a `Bar` relationship to all nodes listed in the array `[c,d,...]`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need specific c,d nodes to match, not just any nodes with Bar relationship. IOW, return 'a' if it has Bar relationship to [c,d,...] list of nodes. More ideas?

Comment: The "WHERE all(... WHERE ... )" syntax is just what I needed. Thanks!